# HTML/php forms: error when submitting links

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form handled by php. The form has various text input fields and one of those asks the user to input a link containing `http://`.

The problem is when I submit a link like `http://www.google.com/` the form fails badly by displaying random content from different php files on my website.

Here's a resume of my code:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="link" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['link']))
    {
        $link = mysql_escape_string($_POST['link']);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(link) values($link)");
    }
?>
```

Works just fine when not submitting a string that contains `http://`. Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: `"displaying random content from different php files on my website"` - That's... really strange.  Are you sure *this* code is the problem?  Analyze the symptom more, when a page renders what causes it to display random content from other files?  Inserting a record into a database table most definitely does *not* display random content to users.  It doesn't display anything to anybody.  Other code is doing that.  When you debug that other code, where is that content coming from?

Comment: I don't have a single echo statement on my add.php file. It displays content from my main index.php file, which is in a completely different folder.

Comment: Even more strange, the code fails only on the web server. I have apache with xampp in my PC and it runs perfectly.

Comment: Either way, there isn't any information we can use to diagnose or solve the issue.  Nothing in the posted code would cause this behavior.  The problem may be a *combination* of this code and something else, but we can't know.  For all we know this "random content" could just be an `iframe` in the response.

Comment: SQL injection? The mysql api as you use it is deprecated, you should switch to pdo or mysqli and parameterized queries.

Comment: Change `values($link)` to `values('$link')` wrapping with quotes, which is most likely the problem. @user3141607

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote*: You will find an `mysqli_*` based version further down.

Assuming you are connected to your DB, you did not wrap `$link` in `VALUES` with quotes.

Change this line:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(link) values( $link )");
                                              ^     ^ <- missing quotes
```

to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(link) values('$link')");
```

Tested and working with this example: (form is set to self) and using `http://www.google.com/` as an input and a few others containing `http://`

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASS', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$dbh = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

if(!$dbh)
{
    die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

if(!$db_select)
{
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['link'])){
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (link) values('$link')");
if(!mysql_query)
{
    die("sorry");
}
else{ echo "Success"; }

mysql_close();

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <title></title>
    <h3>Place your Link Below:</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="link" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Do consider switching to `mysqli_*` functions with prepared statements or PDO. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future releases.

---

Here is an `mysqli_*` based version:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASS', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$dbh = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

if(!$dbh)
{
    die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$db_select = mysqli_select_db($dbh,DB_NAME);

if(!$db_select)
{
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['link'])){

$link = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['link']);

mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO mytable (link) values('$link')");
if(!mysqli_query)
{
    die("sorry");
}
else{ echo "Success"; }

mysqli_close($dbh);

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <h3>Please Place your Order Below:</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="link" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </body>
</html>
```